# Performance problems trying to preview video from webcam

Tags: c#, windows, webcam

I have a small application I wrote that simply displays a preview of webcam or my capture card. At the moment it works exactly how I want it to, with the exception that the capture card displays at a much lower framerate than I'd like it to.

Here is my relevant code:

```
    private const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = 1034;
    private const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW = 1074;
    private const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE = 1076;
    private const int WM_CAP_SET_SCALE = 1077;
    private const int WS_CHILD = 1073741824;
    private const int WS_VISIBLE = 268435456;
    private const short SWP_NOMOVE = 2;
    private const short SWP_NOZORDER = 4;
    private const short HWND_BOTTOM = 1;
    private const int iDevice = 0;
    private int hHwnd;
    private int previewRate = 34;
    private int width = 640;
    private int height = 480;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SendMessageA")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SetWindowPos")]
    static extern int SetWindowPos(int hwnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool DestroyWindow(int hndw);

    [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
    public static extern int capCreateCaptureWindow(string lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, int hwndParent, int nID);

    private void OpenPreviewWindow() 
    {
        hHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindow(iDevice.ToString(), (WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD), 0, 0, width, height, Handle.ToInt32(), 0);

        //  Connect to device
        if (SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, iDevice, 0) != -1) 
        {
            SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, 1, 0);
            SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, previewRate, 0);
            SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, 1, 0);
            SetWindowPos(hHwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, width, height, (SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER));
        }
        else 
        {
            DestroyWindow(hHwnd);
        }
    }
```

When I preview the capture card in an application like FMLE, it previews at 30 FPS, which is my target framerate (~34 milliseconds per frame,) however when I use my application to preview it's closer to 10-15 FPS. I should probably also note that my program will preview 30 FPS from my webcam. What could be causing the problem with the capture card, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you send `WM_CAP_GET_SEQUENCE_SETUP`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743905(v=VS.85).aspx, to the capture window and examine the `CAPTUREPARAMS` structure, does the `dwRequestMicroSecPerFrame` correspond to 30 fps? The default is 15 fps (66667 microseconds). You might look into `WM_CAP_SET_SEQUENCE_SETUP`.

Comment: That's really good advice, but from what I can tell, it seems to be driver-dependent, and doesn't seem to work with my capture card. Are there any other parameters or settings that might affect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DirectShow to view the webcam.

An example would be: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx

or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/webcam_c_sharp.aspx

Comment: This is how I ended up fixing it. However, I went with the Touchless SDK: http://touchless.codeplex.com/releases/view/17986

Comment: Great! avicap32 is old school.